# How to intercept messages about reboot or logoff?

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, win32gui

I tried to find information on this, but only found the WM_QUERYENDSESSION function. How can I use this to intercept reboot / shutdown messages?

```
import win32gui, win32con

msg = win32gui.GetMessage(None, 0, 0)
if msg and msg.message == win32con.WM_QUERYENDSESSION:
    print('EXIT')
```

Here is an example of my code, but when I run it it doesn't handle any actions. and does not intercept shutdown messages

Comment: This is straight from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/wm-queryendsession): *"A window receives this message through its `WindowProc` function."* Why did you avoid reading it?

Answer (score 0):

According to [`WM_QUERYENDSESSION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/wm-queryendsession): The [`WM_QUERYENDSESSION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/wm-queryendsession) message is sent when the user chooses to end the session or when an application calls one of the system shutdown functions. A window receives this message through its [`WindowProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms633573(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function.

So this message will only take effect when sent by the application and accepted in the [`WindowProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms633573(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function.